# DataTables render wrong DateTime value from database

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

i'm using datatable plugin in asp.net mvc project , while binding data it render wrong datetime value

the actual datetime value in database is 05-May-19 2:43:33 PM , in running the displayed value is /Date(1557060213477)/

the expected result it display datetime value that exist in database

here is my model

```
 public int Id { get; set; }
 [Required]
 public string Name { get; set; }
 Display(Name ="Upload File")]
 public string FileUrl { get; set; }
 public DateTime AddedOn { get; set; }
```

here is my view

```
<table id="DDR" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Uploaded File</th>
            <th>Uploaded At</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
@section scripts {
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            $("#DDR").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/DomesticDocRepositories/GetData",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "data": "Id",
                        render: function (data, type) {
                            return '<a href="/DomesticDocRepositories/Details/' + data + '">'+data+"</a>";
                        }
                    },

                    { "data": "Name" },
                    {
                        data: "FileUrl",
                        render: function (data, type) {
                            return "<a href='/DomesticFiles/" + data + " 'target='_blank''>" + data + "</a>";
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "AddedOn",
                        render: function (data, type) {
                            return '<span "title='+ data +"'>" + data +"</span>";
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) { return '<a class="btn btn-info" href="/DomesticDocRepositories/Edit/' + full.Id + '">Edit</a>'; }
                    },
                    {
                        data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                            return '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="/DomesticDocRepositories/Delete/' + row.Id + '">Delete</a>';
                        }
                    },
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for datetimes ([docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/)).in your render, you should use in render:

```
{
    render: function (data, type, row) {//data
        return moment(row.AddedOn ).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss');//or another format you wantt.
    }
}
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined @hassan

Comment: sorry I forgot to write about `moment.js`, I edit my answer.